# How to describe a set of coordinates of variable length?

Tags: probability, logic, notation

I need to describe a set of coordinates with up to 8 dimensions. A problem is asking me to describe an event from a experiment involving sampling. The catch is that the experiment doesn't end until a condition is met, not after a specific number of samples.

I can describe a set with a specific number of samples (e.g. $A = \{ (x, y)\ |\ x,y \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

How would this work for coordinates between 1 and 8?

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you provide more information. For example: What is the experiment? Where are you sampling from? What is the condition for ending the experiment? What event are you trying to describe?

Answer (score 2):

Taking your example, this could be a set with elements whoose coordinates are at most 8.
$$A=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)~|~ n,x_i\in\mathbb{N}, n\leq 8, i=1,\ldots,n\}$$

Or it could be the union
$$A = \cup_{k=1}^8 B_k$$
where $B_k = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_k) ~|~ (x_1,\ldots,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k\}$